# How below column transform into double column with ascending group(sql)

Tags: sql, rdbms

I try to get this in single query but failed.
Do we need to use group set?

| colA |
| --- |
| 200 |
| 400 |
| 300 |
| 500 |
| 200 |

transform into

| colA | colB |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | 1 |
| 300 | 2 |
| 300 | 2 |
| 400 | 3 |
| 500 | 4 |

Comment: Please have an eye on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms . Also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use DENSE_RANK() windowing function if available in your SQL database

like

```
select ColA, 
DENSE_RANK() OVER( order by ColA) as colB
from yourtable
```

Comment: It depends on RDMBS, doesn't it?

Comment: @Reporter yes it does. I answered to give OP an idea as likely his question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

If your RDBMS supports it you can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY colA)`

```
create table t (colA int);
insert into t values (300),(400),(300),(500),(200);
```

```
select
  row_number() over (order by colA) colB,
  colA
from t
order by colA
```

> ```
> colB | colA
> ---: | ---:
>    1 |  200
>    2 |  300
>    3 |  300
>    4 |  400
>    5 |  500
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=afbc97297b2ba23a6f95d6bd681201fb)*